# Storing Admin Accounts and Root Sites with Multi-Tenanted Site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

I am creating a mufti-tenanted ASP.NET MVC website.

1. Sites are hierarchical, and all sites inevitably lead to one 'root' site.
2. Create super admin users.

Is there a suggested way for handling the initial creation of these objects?  Here are the options that I see:

1. Store them in Web.config (but if I store the passwords of super admins, would they be secure?)
2. Create all of these objects in the Seeding method (I am using Entity Framework CodeFirst).
3. Use a PreApplicationStartMethod to ensure that they exist.

What is the standard method here?

Comment: Have you considered using something like `SimpleMembershipProvider`?

Comment: I'm using Identity (which is the upgraded version of SimpleMembership) - but that does not solve my issue - I am thinking that the Site needs to have the ability to have a SuperAdmin without directly relying on the Identity framework - otherwise, how would the first Super Admin be created?

Comment: I haven't use `Identity` so I'm not sure that my suggestion is applicable in your scenario but first - you don't really want this done by seeding. In general seeding is for development purposes to put some dummy data to work with. The web.config is also a bad place for this. What you can do with `SimpleMembershipProvider` and maybe with `Identity` is this : http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/09/05/seeding-membership-amp-roles-in-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx

Comment: And also using something like this : `if (!context.Database.Exists())
                        {
                            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                        }` I think this is more elegant way because like this you are keeping the things separated.

Comment: I'm thinking about doing something like this in the Application_Start() - do you think that would be a good place to run it?

Comment: That's exactly how I've done it in my project. I'll post as answer how I've done this with `SimpleMembershipProvider` since it's pretty large and see if you can adjust it to be used with `Identity` and give feedback if it works with `Identity` too :)

Comment: Sweet!  I think that they are pretty compatible -

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I solved this problem using `SimpleMembershipProvider` if they are similar enough maybe you can easily adjust this code to your needs:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
        private static object _initializerLock = new object();
        private static bool _isInitialized;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
        }

        private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);

                try
                {
                    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
                    {
                        if (!context.Database.Exists())
                        {
                            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                        }
                    }

                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DAL.MyDbContext", "UserProfiles", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
                    if (!Roles.RoleExists("SuperAdmin"))
                    {
                        Roles.CreateRole("SuperAdmin");
                        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("SuperAdmin", "12345");
                        Roles.AddUsersToRole(new[] { "SuperAdmin" }, "SuperAdmin");
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is in my main project in folder `Filters`. And then in `Global.asax.cs` :

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //All the other stuff..
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    }
```

Comment: why do you use a filter instead of just putting (for instance) the SimpleMembershipInitializer() method in the Application_start() method?  Doesn't Application_Start() only run at the start of the application?

Comment: @William To be honest, more of this code is taken and not created by myself. I could try to throw some answers but a fast check showed that there are good articles on this topic that could give you those answers so better search there. It seems that if your membership provider is not initialized globally you get into lots of trouble.